# Allow special characters for password

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

In my MVC2 site if a user enters lt/gt signs in a password box an exception is thrown because of "potentially dangerous..". ValidateInput(false) on my controller solves it but for something so simple (not html passing) yet needs to be protected what is a better alternative? I've briefly looked at http://wpl.codeplex.com/ but it also seems overkill

Thoughts? Your solution?

Answer (score 0):

use Javascript onsubmit event and [escap](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) your inputs before posting it to the server. that will allow you to do what you want.

You can [unescap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.aspx) the data at server side as well.

Comment: JavaScript isn't a reliable solution. It can be disabled.